# If statement using KeyCharaters

Tags: java, key-events

```
public static void displayInfo(KeyEvent e){
int id = e.getID();

String keyString;
   char c = e.getKeyChar();
    keyString =  ""+c;


    if (keyString=="w"){
        System.out.print("FACE");
    }
}
```

this is my code and for whatever reason it wont work. Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not compare strings with the `==` operator. Instead, use the `equals` method. So, change this line:

```
if (keyString=="w"){
```

to this:

```
if (keyString.equals("w")){
```